# RIA Not Loading Child Entities With RIA & Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, ria

I am having difficulty loading some child attributes of a given entity. I have managed to load child entities on other objects, but not this one. To add to the frustration, the child entities I am trying to load are referenced from another Entity, and from this they work fine...

My code is as follows.

**ViewWasteApplication Page**

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnNavigatedTo(ByVal e As System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs)

    If NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("ID") Then

        ' load an existing record - edit mode
        Context.Load(Context.GetWasteApplicationsByIDQuery(Int32.Parse(NavigationContext.QueryString("ID").ToString())),
                     AddressOf wasteApplicationLoaded, Nothing)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Application not found")
    End If

End Sub
```

This calls GetWasteApplicationsByID - which is as follows:

```
Public Function GetWasteApplicationsByID(ByVal query As Int32) As IQueryable(Of WasteApplication)
    Dim result = Me.ObjectContext.WasteApplications.Include("CurrentlyWith") _
                                             .Include("Packaging") _
                                             .Include("WasteStream") _
                                             .Where(Function(f) f.ID = query)
    Return result
End Function
```

The WasteApplication is being returned, but neither of the 3 child entities are appearing.

I have created a MetaData class for this WasteApplication, as follows:

```
<MetadataTypeAttribute(GetType(WasteApplications.WasteApplicationsMetaData))> _
Partial Public Class WasteApplications


Friend NotInheritable Class WasteApplicationsMetaData

    'Metadata classes are not meant to be instantiated.
    Private Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub

    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property RequestedByName As String
    Public Property RequestedByExtension As String
    Public Property CARQRequired As Boolean
    Public Property OriginOfMaterialID As Integer
    Public Property Comments As String
    Public Property MaterialName As String
    Public Property PackagingID As Integer
    Public Property FacilityPath As String
    Public Property ProcessStatus As String
    Public Property DateSubmitted As DateTime
    Public Property RequestedByUsername As String
    Public Property CurrentlyWithID As Integer
    Public Property WasteStreamID As Integer

    <Include()>
    Public Property WasteStream As WasteStreams

    <Include()>
    Public Property Packaging As Packaging


End Class
End Class
```

Can anyone see anything wrong with this? I load the same two child objects on another page, and these seem to load just fine. The code for this is as follows:

**View Chemical Application (This works)**

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnNavigatedTo(ByVal e As   System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs)
         Context.Load(Context.GetChemicalApplicationsByIDQuery(Int32.Parse(NavigationContext.QueryString("ID"))),
                     AddressOf wasteApplicationLoaded, Nothing)

End Sub
```

With the RIA function as follows:

```
Public Function GetChemicalApplicationsByID(ByVal query As Int32) As IQueryable(Of ChemicalApplication)
    Return Me.ObjectContext.ChemicalApplications.Include("Chemical") _
                                                .Include("ProcessStatus") _
                                                .Include("PlanningApprover") _
                                                .Include("FacilitiesApprover") _
                                                .Include("MaintenanceApprover") _
                                                .Include("PPCPermit") _
                                                .Include("DischargeConsent") _
                                                .Include("Facility") _
                                                .Include("Packaging") _
                                                .Include("WasteStream") _
                                                .Where(Function(f) f.ID = query)
End Function
```

Any suggestions?

NOTE: I have not posted any of the XAML bindings, as I have confirmed via debugging that the source entities do not contain the child data, so therefore binding will not be an issue.

I am using Silverlight 4 with Entity Framework 4.

Comment: Further to above - setting a breakpoint in `GetWasteApplicationsByID` reveals that `result` contains the child elements, but when `wasteApplicationLoaded` is called indicating the data has loaded, the child elements are not present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue, you need to load the respective entities into the datacontext as well as loading the linked entity. i.e in my case I need to add:

```
Context.Load(Context.GetWasteStreamsQuery())
Context.Load(Context.GetPackagingQuery())
```

so that the linked child entities exist. My full onNavigate therefore looks like this:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnNavigatedTo(ByVal e As System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs)

    If NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("ID") Then


        Context.Load(Context.GetWasteApplicationsByIDQuery(Int32.Parse(NavigationContext.QueryString("ID").ToString())),
                 AddressOf wasteApplicationLoaded, Nothing)

        Context.Load(Context.GetWasteStreamsQuery())
        Context.Load(Context.GetPackagingQuery())
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Application not found")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Gavin,  
Won't your solution effectively pull ALL the WasteStreams and all the Packaging items to the client side just so the relevant ones can be bound to your WasteApplication item? Or is RIA performing some sort of extra magic that I'm not aware of? Or am I just missing the point entirely?  
I'd appreciate any feedback you can provide because I've got the exact same problem at the moment.  
Cheers,     
Scott

Answer (score 3):

You will need to create metadata classes for the entities you wish to include and mark the fields with the `[Include]` attribute.

```
[MetadataTypeAttribute(typeof(Client.ClientMetadata))]
public partial class Client
{
    internal sealed class ClientMetadata
    {
        private ClientMetadata()
        {
        }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="You must enter a client name")]
        public string Name;

        [Include]
        public EntityCollection<Contact> Contacts;

        [Include]
        public Employee Employee;

        [Include]
        public BillTo BillTo;
    }
    }
```

See [RIA Services and relational data](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/01/05/master-details-with-ria-services-and-includedresults.aspx) for more.

Comment: As mentioned in my original post, I have created a metadata class for the object, however despite marking these fields as `include`, they do not load

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the 2 following things in order for this to work:

a) Add the include parameter in a metadata class (as DaveB proposed)

b) on the domain service queries (server side) add the include directive - Me.ObjectContext.WasteApplications.Include("CurrentlyWith")